# Cucumber with TestNG - cannot run mutiple tag

Tags: java, selenium, maven, cucumber, testng

When I am running a testNG test with one tag, it runs smoothly, otherwhise, when I add the second tag, then Browser opens, closes immediately and I get the result below:

## 0 Scenarios
0 Steps
0m0.115s

TestSuite
Total tests run: 0, Passes: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0

An example using 2 tags (I just remove the ' and @DP' part in it works):

1LI is basically a login feature

```
package stepdefinitions;

//import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
//import cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;
import io.cucumber.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;
import io.cucumber.testng.CucumberOptions;

//import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger;
//import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.log4testng.Logger;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

//this TestRunner class is used by Eclipse TestNG run config

@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/java/features/", 
glue ="stepdefinitions.ExampleStepDefinitions",
plugin = {"summary","pretty","html:target/html/cucumber-html-report", 
        "json:c:/SeleniumFramework/cucumberriport/target/Json/cucumber.json" },
monochrome = true,
tags =  "@1LI and @DP" )
```

===============================================

POM contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>s.testautomation</groupId>
    <artifactId>testautomation</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>testautomation</name>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>testNG.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>6.3.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-testng -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.3.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-server -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
    <version>3.9.1</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.9.1</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core 
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.3</version>
</dependency> -->
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng-->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>7.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>8.2.2.jre11</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.mkolisnyk</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-reports</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Could anyone please help out? I just started with Java and Selenium, so it might be something trivial for an expert. I am struggling with this for 3 days.
With the old Cucumber and old imports the package works with two tags. I cannot see any indication that this is a syntax error either.

Thanks in advance!
Tamas

Comment: Do you have a scenario with both tags?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the fast input. Actually I had no tags, just separately. 1LI for Login, DP for Domestic Payment.  I have figured it out one hour ago. I took over this project as a rookie as someone has left the company. She was  importing info.cukes, but I thought I will upgrade everything. In the depreceted cucumber version this worked {"@1LI,@DP"}.I just have not realized that this is an 'or' and not an 'and'.After digging on the cucumber website, I have realized that I need to use tags =  "@1LI or @DP".

Comment: This will run the login and then the domestic payment, because there are features with these tags and the order is given after tags. Using tags =  "@DP or @1LI" will try to run the domestic payment and then the login. Correct me if I am wrong about the sequence. Thanks again.

Comment: There was a reason we got rid of the comma syntax. :D

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, it is working for me

```
tags = {"@run1, @run2, @alertBAT, @DeviceCreate"}
```